# Time taken to execute a java method is zero?

Tags: java, methods, time

I am reading the system time just before the method is invoked and immediately after method returns and taking the time difference, which will give the time taken by a method for execution.

**Code snippet**

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis ();
method ();
long end = System.currentTimeMillis ();

System.out.println ("Time taken for execution is " + (end - start));
```

The strange thing is the output is `0`..how is this possible..?

Comment: Because it actually executes in less than a millisecond? If not, what combination of OS and JDK do you use which triggers such a result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chances are it's taking a shorter time than the fairly coarse-grained system clock. (For example, you may find that `System.currentTimeMillis()` only changes every 10 or 15 milliseconds.)

`System.currentTimeMillis` is good for finding out the current time, but it's not fine-grained enough for measuring short durations. Instead, you should use [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) which uses a high-resolution timer. `nanoTime()` is *not* suitable for finding the current time -  but it's designed for measuring durations.

Think of it as being the difference between a wall clock and a stopwatch.

Comment: @Jon Skeet- Was i just answered by you..:O,can't believe top user answered it..?..Thanks..:)

Comment: @sum2000  SO should provide button called `I am feeling lucky` :)

Comment: Even nanoTime might only have a one micro-second accuracy. Additionally it is a method call in itself and can take a surprisingly long time on some OSes, i.e. longer that the time of the method you are testing. A solution to this is to call the method for at least 2 second repeatedly, and take an average.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Yes, that's certainly better where possible - but in some cases it's not appropriate (in particular when measuring time in a real production system, where you really want a stopwatch rather than a wall clock, but you can't artificially increase the load).

Answer (score 5):

use [`nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)

Comment: "This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond accuracy"

Comment: @sum See the doc it says,_This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond accuracy. No guarantees are made about how frequently values change. Differences in successive calls that span greater than approximately 292 years (263 nanoseconds) will not accurately compute elapsed time due to numerical overflow_

Comment: Whew..don't tell me that was on your head while answering.;)

Comment: Can you edit the information from your comment into the answer itself?

Answer (score 1):

Because it took less than 1 millisecond?

If you want to get a more meaningful metric, I would suggest calling your method in a loop 1000000 times, timing that, and then dividing by 1000000.

Of course, even then, that might not be representative; the effects on the cache will be different, etc.

Comment: i checked using `nanoSecond()` method..thanks for your help too.